# generating a webservice client

Tags: java, web-services

Please I want to generate a webservice client from a wsdl through a command line (or java code) and i want to have all this classes generated ( This can be done manually in eclipse by creating a webservice client) :

I want to have for example :

```
getrecordsrespondsgetrecordsresult.java 
thewebservice.java
thewebserviceLocator.java
XXXXSOAP.java
XXXXSOAPPROXY.java
XXXXSTUB.java
```

I have already tried with the wsimport and WSDL2java but it doesnt generate all the classes I need maybe i didnt put the right options.

Thank you.

Comment: just an observation, use correct naming conventions for .java files. For eg: TheWebService.java or TheWebserviceLocator.java

Answer (score 0):

Try wsdl2java -client HelloWorld.wsdl

More details here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

Assuming you are using one of the favorite tools Apache CXF.

Comment: I tried wsdl2java of Apache CXF and Apache Axis but none of them gave me all the classes that i needed. Because i need to keep the same structure as cited on my post. In eclipse when generating this manually we specify the level of generation which is deploy client and also there is a checked box : generate client. do you have any clue about this ?

Comment: I finally found a solution, i needed to use apache axis-1_4 with the command line : java -classpath %AXISCLASSPATH% org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java xxxx.wsdl. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

> WSDL2Java -role "client" -verbose
>   C:\Users\n118941\Desktop\jaxb\ProvInformation.wsdl